# Pass var to angular $resource success function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I've been going crazy over this and I think the answer is probably out there but I don't know the right way to ask Google the question.

Essentially I need a way to make a $resource call, and pass in some data that I want to then use in the success function.

```
app.controller('VariantListController', ['djResource', function(djResource){
    var Variants = djResource('/ship-builder/variants/?format=json');
    var Vehicle = djResource('/ship-builder/vehicles/:id', {id: '@id'});
    this.variants = Variants.query(function(variants){
        $(variants).each(function(){
            console.log(this);
            variantData = this;
            var vehicleData = Vehicle.get({id:this.baseVehicle}, function(){
                console.log(variantData);
            })
        })
    });

}]);
```

In the above example, in the innermost success function, 'variantData' is always the value of the LAST entry from the previous level.  This makes sense because the value was set by the last item in the array long before the success happens.  I need a way though to have the value of the 'variantData' that was inexistince when the Vehicle.get() was called.

Does that make sense? I find it very hard to explain the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a closure to make it work. Something like

```
this.variants = Variants.query(function(variants){
        $(variants).each(function(){
            getVehicleData(this);
        })
    });

function getVehicalData(variantData) {
   var vehicleData = Vehicle.get({id:variantData.vehicleId}, function(){
                console.log(variantData);
            })
}
```

Comment: You know, this makes sense.  Let me give it a try.

Comment: This worked like a charm, and makes total sense in hindsight as well.  Thank you for your great answer and in helping me learn a bit more.  I am new to Javascript and I guess I got caught up in how nested it tends to be, going farther than I should have!.

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means an expert on the $resource service, but perhaps using the $promise.then method instead of the success callback would work.

```
$(variants).each(function(){
  console.log(this);
  variantData = this;

  Vehicle.get({id:this.baseVehicle}).$promise.then(function() {
    console.log(variantData);
  });
});
```

Comment: I've tried playing around with $promise but have been unable to get it to work.  I always get an error saying $promise is undefined.

Comment: Well you're using djResource and not $resource so maybe there's a problem in the way you're wrapping $resource with djResource that causes $promise to be undefined.

Comment: I guess its possibly a bug in the service, though its supposed to have an identical API.

Answer (score 0):

Since the value in variantData may change before the success callback is actually called, you want to ensure the the callback has the original value stored.

```
var vehicleData = Vehicle.get({id:this.baseVehicle}, function(vData){
     return function() {
          console.log(vData);
     }
}(variantData));
```

The above will create a new function with variantData stored in a closure.